# Memcache Latency Time Too High?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, jpql, low-latency

I have below code working on GAE. When getting the items from memcache I get a latency around 30 ms for 5 to 20 results only. Isn't it too high? Is there anyway I can improve it?

```
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
        @ApiMethod(name = "queryDesire2")
        public List<String> queryDesire2(
                @Nullable @Named("name2") String name2){
            EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
            List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
            Key userKey=null;
            Long x=0L;
            List<Key> keysNew = new ArrayList<Key>();
            MemcacheService memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

            try {
                    userKey=KeyFactory.createKey(name2,1);
                    if (memcache.get(userKey)==null) {
                        Query query2 = mgr.createQuery("select d.good from Desire d where d.ctgry = :name2");        
                        list1 = query2.setParameter("name2", name2).getResultList();          

                        for (String d : list1){
                        x=x+1L;
                        userKey = KeyFactory.createKey(name2,x);                            
                        memcache.put(userKey, d);
                        memcache.put(name2+"no", x);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Long y=(Long) memcache.get(name2+"no");
                    for (x = 1L; x<=y; x++){
                        userKey=KeyFactory.createKey(name2,x);
                        keysNew.add(userKey);
                    }   
                        Map mMap;
                        mMap = memcache.getAll(keysNew);
                        list1 = new ArrayList<String>(mMap.values());
                    }

             }
            finally {
                mgr.close();
            }
            return list1;


        }
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

I captured this snapshot from https://appengine.google.com/... logs. I assumed that 26ms on the top one is the latency. But also I realized there is cpu_usd: 0.000035. What my real concern is to understand how much instance hour will my application use. Is there any formula or way to calculate that?

Comment: How did you calculate the latency on Memcache calls?

Comment: I just check the latency time given in the logs on the app engine console.

Comment: I don't see separate entries for Memcache calls. And if you look at your overcall call, you need to account for all the other things that you do, including your query.

Comment: Have you measure this using [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats)?

Comment: @user3370788 the 26ms is the Request Latency and not the Memcache API call latency. To get the API Latency, you will need to enable Appstats as mentioned previously. If your real concern is to know how much instance hour will your application use, I advice running a Load Test Experiment and determine how many instances you will need to run x number of QPS. Once you know the number of instances you will need in avg, you can use the [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to get an estimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all objects in a single call. You can also use AsyncMemcacheService - it will work a little faster with put calls.

Just remember:

> The "multi" batch operations can have any number of elements. The
>   total size of the call and the total size of the data fetched must not
>   exceed 32 megabytes.

Comment: I use memcache.getAll() to do that. Isn't it the way to do it?

Comment: I said that you can batch `put` calls.

Answer (score 3):

The memcache available through App Engine is either [shared or dedicated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/memcache). With shared, which is what I assume you're using, you're in a pool with other users, and latency is going to depend a lot on what they're up to at the moment.